# manual contribution entry not showing up on contacts contribution summary

Tags: civicontribute, pledges, civipledge, summaryfields

I am brand new to CiviCRM :)  4.7.4
We are using WordPress for our website 4.6.1

I am trying to manually enter a contribution and/or a pledge as I am testing out the new  database with just a few contacts.
I am trying to add a contribution manually one by one to a donor that already
exists in the database.
Also did this with a pledge

Contact selected: Daffy Duck
Selected Contributions tab, then new contribution

Financial type - Campaign Contribution
Total Amount = 875.00 (US$)
Source = Board
Contribution status = Pending (since this is one of 4 payments to be made)

Soft Credit - N/A

Under Payment Details:
Received: March 24, 2016 Time: 10:00 a.m.
payment method = Check
Check no. = 9083
transaction id = blank
Receipt date = July 27, 2016 Time: 12:22 pm

Under Additional Details:
Non-deductible amount = $22.00
Fee amount = blank n/a
Net amount = 875.00
all other fields left blank

Hit the SAVE button and said contribution was saved to contact

But when I go to the Contributions or Pledge summary page for that contact it does not show any dollar amount for the contribution of $875 that I
put in.

the first column which should show the $875 only shows a blue Dollar sign ($)
with **no amount**.
Type "campaign contribution" and Source "Board" appear as they should

why is the amount not showing up?
Thank you for your assistance.
BB

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how your finance type "campaign contribution" is set up and also tell us what version you are running?

Comment: Thanks Christia for responding.  I am really  new at this, just starting so appreciate your help. Wordpress 4.7.4    The Finance type is the default

Comment: Your CiviCRM also has a version, unrelated to your word press version. I looked the way you entered it and that seems correct. Have you tried deleting your cancelled transaction?

Comment: Default campaign contribution from the drop down menu for that field. By the way, I do not have a contribution page set up.  We are still using the Support us or donate button on our website that was set up prior to obtaining CiviCRM.   www.romesymphony.org

Comment: No, not sure how to delete the cancelled transaction.

Comment: how do I find the CiviCRM version?

Comment: Not sure about with Wordpress, but it should be at the bottom of the page when you're in the CiviCRM. Also, to delete a transaction, there should be a link to the far right of it in the list that says, "Delete". Depending on your version.

Comment: CRM version is the 4.7.4 and was able to delete the cancelled transaction. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did deleting the cancelled transaction solve the problem?

Comment: The information you provided on your other post would have been helpful here. Link: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/total-amount-of-contribution-or-pledge-not-showing-up-in-summary-or-on-email-rec

Answer (score 1):

If you have two transactions entered that are exactly the same and both pending, but one is cancelled, it may have created a conflict in the system. Try deleting the cancelled transaction and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried that and didn't work. Works ok in demo but not on my civiCRM - configuration problem?

Comment: Sorry. I just saw your other post. The information you provided there would have been helpful here. Link: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/total-amount-of-contribution-or-pledge-not-showing-up-in-summary-or-on-email-rec